# NHibernate list index mapping to non nullable database column

Tags: c#, nhibernate, list, indexing

I´m trying to map a list using NHibernate that is part of a parent-child relationship. The database structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[salesvouchers](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[id_vouchertype] [int] NOT NULL,
[id_salespoint] [int] NOT NULL) /*and a couple more fields*/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[salesvouchersitems](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[id_salesvoucher] [int] NOT NULL,
[itemposition] [int] NOT NULL)
```

Both tables are related by the id_salesvoucher column that has a foreign key. The problem is that the itemposition column is meant to be the index of the SalesVoucherItem list. Using this mapping file for the salesvoucher class:

```
<class name="SalesVoucher" table="salesvouchers">
      <id name="Id" column="id">
         <generator class="native" />
      </id>
      <list name="Items" table="salesvouchersitems" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
         <key column="id_salesvoucher"/>
         <index column="itemposition"/>
         <one-to-many class="SalesVoucherItem"/>
      </list>
   <!--and more fields not relevant here-->
   </class>
```

This seems to be fine, but when doing a test to insert a new SalesVoucher class into the database with a few SalesVoucherItem in the list, it throws the SQL error:
"Cannot insert NULL into the itemposition column. Column does not accept nulls"

It seems that NH is trying to insert a NULL in the position, which makes no sense to me, as the index in a list is a mandatory data and should be declared as such in the database.
Any ideas? Thanks for the help! Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must expose the itemposition column as a property and set its value. NHibernate can't do that for you.